# Entity Framework 5 on Windows Server Web (SP2) x64 and IIS7.0

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5, windows-server

I have a test website running on a test server with Windows Server Web (SP2) installed. I've just installed .NET4.5 on it. In the website (simple ASP.NET webforms from template) I've used Entity Framework 5 Spatial types, very simple code just for testing which runs fine on my local dev machine:

```
var conn = new DbEntities();
var geo = conn.tbl_SpatialData.First().GeoInfo;
var geom = DbGeometry.FromGml(geo.AsGml());
litText.Text = geom.AsGml();
```

However on the server it gives me this error:

**Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.**

The sql database where it wants to connect is on a different server, and is a SQL Server 2008 -> I am connecting to the same db from my local dev machine.

I've already tried searching for the dll on my local machine, and adding it to the website's bin folder, however it gives me a new error requesting for another dll. I would like to have those dlls installed globally like on my dev machine. What am I missing or should I install on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That assembly and its dependencies are part of SQL Server Managements Objects. This feature must be installed on the server. It should be part of SQL Server's Client Tools or Client Tools SDK.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you when this comes in published server

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx

> If you have control over the server you can just install the CLR Types
>   for SQL Server. The SQL Server 2012 SP1 version of the CLR Types can
>   be [downloaded here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580). `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` is the installer you want and
>   there is an x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) version depending on the
>   architecture of the machine you are deploying to.
>
> However, installing extra software on the target machine is not always
>   an option – especially if you are deploying to a machine you don’t own
>   (such as Windows Azure Web Sites). Fortunately the required assemblies
>   can be deployed along with your application.
>
> Step 1: Install the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/).
>
> ```
> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
> ```
>
> Step 2: Ensure the appropriate version of the native
>   `SqlServerSpatial110.dll` assembly is copied to the output directory
>   and deployed with your application.
>
> Steps on how to do this are included in a ReadMe.txt file that will
>   open in Visual Studio when you install the package.